# connect to ssh and execute command in spite of changing shells after login

Tags: bash, ssh, zsh, command, remote

I am trying to connect to a server via ssh and then execute a command.
So far so simple.

The twist is that on that server, I start zsh from my bash. So in my .bashrc I have the command:

```
exec /bin/zsh -l
```

So that when I login, it automatically starts my z-shell. And I want to keep it like that.

Unfortunately, when I run my bash script to connect to the server and run a command, it does not work. No error message, the command just runs endlessly.

Is there a way to do this in in spite of the shell change?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to keep running `zsh` from `bash`? If you always use `zsh` it'd make more sense to run `chsh` to change your login shell.

Comment: thanks for the tip, however, chsh does not work because we are using ldap and chsh.ldap returns a segmentation fault. I spend ours on trying to get that work lol

Comment: All `chsh` really does (afaik) is edit `/etc/passwd`, so you might be able to get the same result with `root` and a text editor.

Comment: we have a different config, none of the users are in /etc/passwd

Comment: also, unfortunately, I don't have root rights

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

In the .bashrc, check whether or not the shell is in interactive mode. If yes, open z shell.

```
if [[ $- == *i* ]]
then
    exec /bin/zsh -l
fi
```

That way, if you execute a bash script that connects to the server and executes the command, z shell won't be started.